# Does Python have a default constructor for classes?

Tags: python, class, constructor

I was asking myself whether Python3.6 had a default constructor for classes. So I wrote some code to test this. But I'm left with more questions than when I started testing this.

I'm trying to understand why myCat constructed ok on line 11 of my program, yet I can't explain why line 27 of my program demanded to know itself

Please, if you can help, review this Python code and the output... does it make sense? 
I made 2 files animal.py and an_test_program.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#animal.py file  ==============================
class animal:
    name = ""
    height = 0
    weight = 0

    def __init__( self, name, height, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

    def printvars(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.height)
        print(self.weight)


#!/usr/bin/env python3
#an_animal_program.py ==============================
import animal as an

#Instantiate a variable of type animal using the special constructor of the class
myDog = an.animal('Capitan', 30, 70)
print('myDog\'s name is ' + myDog.name)
myDog.printvars()

#now play around with Python and discover some things...
#Instantiate a variable of type animal without using the special constructor
myCat = an.animal
print('myCat\'s name is ' + myCat.name)
print('myCat\'s height is ' + "%d" % (myCat.height))
print('myCat\'s weight is ' + "%d" % (myCat.weight))

#notice everything in myCat is empty or zero
#thats because myCat is not initialized with data
#none-the-less myCat is a viable object, otherwise Python would puke out myCat

myCat.name = 'Backstreet'
print('myCat\'s name is ' + myCat.name) # now myCat.name has data in it
    #Ouch... this next line produces an error:
    #myCat.printvars()
    #"an_test_program.py", line 21, in <module>
    #    myCat.printvars()
    #TypeError: printvars() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
myCat.printvars(myCat)   #ok, I'm rolling with it, but this is wierd !!!

#oh well, enough of the wierdness, see if the myCat var can be
#reinstantiated with an animal class that is correctly constructed
myCat = an.animal('Backstreet', 7, 5)
myCat.printvars()

#I'm trying to understand why myCat constructed ok on line 11
#But I can't explain why line 27 demanded to know itself
#the output is:
# RESTART: an_test_program.py 
#myDog's name is Capitan
#Capitan
#30
#70
#myCat's name is 
#myCat's height is 0
#myCat's weight is 0
#myCat's name is Backstreet
#Backstreet
#0
#0
#Backstreet
#7
#5
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `.__init__` is the instance _initializer_. The instance constructor is called `.__new__`. Classes inherit the `.__new__` method from `object`, and generally there's no need to override it, although it's certainly possible to do so.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. Also see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) for a brief summary, with cute diagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't construct anything. You only created another reference to the `animal` class.

That class has `name`, `height` and `weight` attributes already, so the `print()` statements can access those attributes and print the values. You can also give those class attributes a different value, so `myCat.name = 'Backstreet'` works *too*. This change would also be visible through `animal.name` however.

`myCat.printvars` is a reference to the method you defined, but it is *unbound*; there is no instance here, only a class object, so there is nothing to set `self` to. You can pass in a value for `self` explicitly in this case, which is why `myCat.printvars(myCat)` works; you explicitly set `self` to `myCat`, and again that class object has the required attributes for this to work..

You can still create actual instances from the `myCat` reference:

```
an_actual_cat = myCat('Felix', 10, 15)
```

Just remember, all names in Python are references; you can always make more references to objects by assigning:

```
foo = an.animal
bar = an.animal
```

Now both `foo` and `bar` also point to the `animal` class.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I did not recognize that I made references to class objects and references its internal functions. It now is most clear what the code really was doing.